# How to remove rel="nofollow" from feed page

Tags: wordpress, nofollow

In [this](http://smarteinc.com/feed/) page every link has `rel="nofollow"`.

can you guys please tell me how to remove the nofollow from that page.

I am using WordPress them.

Hoping to receive some help from your side

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can create your own feed templates ny following the codex : https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds

Answer (score 0):

To remove nofollow from link please add the below code in your current active theme **functions.php** file.

The rss hook not allow to change content within tag, so create custom template for your feed.

```
/**
 * Deal with the custom RSS templates.
 */
function my_custom_rss() {

    if ( 'photos' === get_query_var( 'post_type' ) ) {
        get_template_part( 'feed', 'photos' );
    } else {
        get_template_part( 'feed', 'rss2' );
    }
}
remove_all_actions( 'do_feed_rss2' );
add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'my_custom_rss', 10, 1 );
```

For more help see this link : [Click here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds#Customizing_Feed_Templates).

You can get the content of custom feed templates from core wordpress folder `/wp-includes/feed-rss2.php`

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi Dinesh, 

Thanks for your quick reply, i tried to put the code which was given by you in function.php but it's not helping, do you have any other option i tried installing plugins "Remove nofollow" but still no success

Comment: Hello @ZahidKhan i have modified my above answer please see this, and let me know are you able to fix the issue.

Comment: Still no success

Comment: hello @ZahidKhan, i have again modified the answer , hook are not allow to change rss content, so you can create your own feed template.

Comment: Hello @ZahidKhan, If it helps you as solution then please mark as an answer, so it can help other developers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following code snippet:

```
global $post;
?>
<?php if ($post->ID == $pageid): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("rel")) {
        $(this).removeAttr("rel");
    }
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```